# How can I connect my Android Application to a database (and what should I be using)

Tags: java, android, database

So I am planning on creating a side project which is similar to Twitter, where the basic functions are to create accounts and store data such as username/password. And for users to create statuses and allow them to be visible on a 'news feed' so it should store the status in the database as well.

The front-end will be developed and designed for Android using Java, but how will I connect it to the database and what should I be using?

Comment: Here you can ask if you are having a problem in your code or too some specific topic. The thing you are asking is a complete tutorial. You should spend some time on Google and you will find your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `firebase` as a back-end database. It is very easy to learn and configure. For more info visit this link: [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)